# Label equations, theorems etc. and not get mad

Tags: cross-referencing

I am writing my thesis, so it's a work in progress where I constantly change equations, put new equations, new Lemmas, Theorems and so on. The big problem is that, for instance, if I label a theorem as "theorem_4.2" or an equation as "equation_2.3" (meaning those are the second theorem of section 4 and the third equation of section 2) and then put a new equation/theorem it messes things up. The solution I've come up with is to add points to my enumeration, so between theorem 4.1 and 4.2 I would put say, a new theorem which I'd label as 4.1.1. Otherwise I would have to rename all the theorems/equations after the new one I've added and also change every `\ref` I've done regarding those.

Is there a simpler way? Any suggestions?

Comment: As you're discovering, the fundamental mistake you're making is to label theorems, equations, etc. by their current number. You'd be much better off if you labeled these objects by their *meaning*, say, `\label{thm:wiles}` or `\label{eqn:fermat}`. This works because the meaning of theorems, equations, etc presumably doesn't depend on the number its assigned in your document.

Comment: Personally, I label with meaningful strings rather than the number – for instance `label{Fat}` for Fatou's lemma.

Comment: @mico sounds like an answer :)

Comment: it is not technically an error to label something as `\label{theorem_4.2}` but it can confuse humans looking at the source who may think that has something to do with the theorem number 4.2 as printed in the document. latex does not assume  that and `\ref{theorem_4.2}` will produce the right text if this is referring to Theorem 4.5 or even Equation 6.2

Comment: @Mico Yeah but I mean, not every equation has that deep meaning, at leat not something explainable in a label. Many of them are just tools to be used

Comment: @tommy1996q - All equations in the document presumably have *some* meaning, right? (Put differently, let's posit that your document doesn't feature truly meaningless equations.) If you're really hard-pressed to come up with a "meaningful" label for some equation, it's ok to use something like `\label{eq:xx}`.

Comment: @Mico yeah they do, but the meaning can be something very technical and hard to explain, at leat in a label. Anyway, thanks for the suggestions!